# Smart whitelisting for a value restricted input

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, whitelist

I need to restrict an input so that the user can only enter dollar amounts. This means that they can enter a string of digits, optionally followed by a decimal and 0-2 more digits. No commas, no dollar signs.

I found what I think is a good pattern for this, but I also want to allow the user to use backspace, enter, tab, etc. I was hoping for a better way to do this than explicitly listing every valid keycode on my whitelist. I was hoping that `/\W/` would do the trick, but alas, it matches too many keypresses.

This is what I currently have.

```
  $input.keypress(function(evt) {
    var ch = String.fromCharCode(evt.which);
    var val = evt.target.value + ch;
    var pattern = /^\d+(\.?(\d{1,2})?)$/;
    if (!pattern.test(val)) {
      evt.preventDefault();
    }
  });
```

If there's a smart and clean way to allow the user to make corrections and to navigate the form with the keyboard, I'd be glad to hear it.

If you have a suggestion for improving the Regex above, please feel free to include that in your answer (or leave it in a comment if you don't have an answer).

Thanks!

Comment: I'd try a regex like this: `\$?[0-9,]+\(?:.[0-9]{2})?`. It'll match `$123,456.00` as well as `123456`.

Comment: @Blender: thanks, I would use that but they actually don't want commas and dollar signs to be entered in the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I do this in my code, I don't run the regex on the keypress itself but on the contents of the field they are typing into.  That way you don't need to worry about non-printing characters.  You will need to worry about them cut-n-pasting into the field which will not fire that keypress event too.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you would do a `keyup` event instead of a `keypress`, that way whatever key was pressed will already have updated the field by the time the event fires. Then you would strip off the last character if the field value doesn't match the pattern. Is this correct?